# RegExp Not providing expected result with cURL

Tags: php, regex, curl, libcurl

Hi below is my code which is not providing expected result.

First it should provide complete html content of page using `cURL` then using regexp which is providing expected result when I provide them direct `htmlcontent` but not providing same result using curl.

Suppose When I pass below content to `htmlcontent` variable then `RegExp` providing proper result.

```
$htmlContent = '<table id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList" class="product-list" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="product-list-item-container" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl00_imbAdd&#39;)">
                                        <a href="/W10542314D/WDoorGasketandLatchSt.aspx">
              <img class="product-list-img" src="/images/products/display/applianceparts.jpg" title="W10542314 D/W Door Gasket & Latch St  " alt="W10542314 D/W Door Gasket & Latch St  " border="0" />
            </a>
                <div class="product-list-options">
          <h5><a href="/W10542314D/WDoorGasketandLatchSt.aspx">W10542314 D/W Door Gasket &amp; Latch St</a></h5>
 <div class="product-list-cost"><span class="product-list-cost-label">Online Price:</span> <span class="product-list-cost-value">$33.42</span></div>
                                  </div>
';
```

Below is my complete code -

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/search.aspx?find=W10130694";
$ch1= curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 20);

$htmlContent= curl_exec($ch1);
echo $htmlContent;


$value=preg_match_all('/.*<div.*class=\"product\-list\-options\".*>.*<a href="(.*)">.*<\/a>.*<\/div>/s',$htmlContent,$matches);
print_r($matches);

$value=preg_match_all('/.*<div.*class=\"product\-list\-item\".*>.*<a href=\"(.*)\">.*<img.*>.*<\/div>/s',$htmlContent,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

In this code it echo htmlcontent of webpage then with regexp it should return `href` of anchor tag between div which class name is `product-list-options` and `product-list-item`

Current output is -

```
http://www.universalapplianceparts.com/termsofservice.aspx
```

### Here Regexp reading my html content from cURL in reverse order and returning first href value in anchor tag.

Expected output in array value - `/W10130694LatchAssyWhiteHandle.aspx`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class="product-list-item".*?<a href="(.*?)".*?class="product-list-options"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU4tW6/1)

Output

```
MATCH 1
1.  [23040-23075]   `/W10130694LatchAssyWhiteHandle.aspx`
```

Explanation:

`class="product-list-item"` matches `class="product-list-item"`
`.*?` matches any character, as few times as possible
`<a href="` matches `<a href="`
`href="(.*?)"` captures text inside `href=""`
`class="product-list-options"` matches `class="product-list-options"`

Comment: Can you please explain your answer . why you sue class on both side